# setting volume level with castv2-client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have [castv2-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/castv2-client) and [google-tts-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-tts-api) used to output audio messages to my google home using ip address. It works fine, but the volume is kind of loud and I'm having issues figuring out how to lower the volume. If I lower the volume manually on google home then the app overrides it and it's loud still. How can I set the volume lower?

Also the console.log("VOLUME", volume) outputs

```
{
  controlType: 'master',
  level: 1,
  muted: false,
  stepInterval: 0.019999999552965164
}
```

```
var Client = require("castv2-client").Client;
var DefaultMediaReceiver = require("castv2-client").DefaultMediaReceiver;
const googleTTS = require("google-tts-api");
var cron = require("node-cron");

function broadcastMessage(message) {
  var App = {
    playin: false,
    DeviceIp: "",
    Player: null,
    GoogleHome: function (host, url) {
      var client = new Client();
      client.connect(host, function () {
        client.launch(DefaultMediaReceiver, function (err, player) {
          client.setVolume({ level: 1 }, function (err, volume) {
            console.log("VOLUME", volume);
            if (err) {
              // Handle error as appropriate
              console.log("Error on setVolume:", err);
            } else {
              console.log("Sending new alert");
            }
          });

          var media = {
            contentId: url,
            contentType: "audio/mp3",
            streamType: "BUFFERED",
          };
          App.Player = player;
          App.Player.load(media, { autoplay: true }, function (err, status) {
            App.Player.on("status", function (status) {
              if (status.playerState === "IDLE" && App.playin === false) {
                client.close();
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
      client.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Error: %s", err.message);
        client.close();
      });
    },
    run: function (ip, text) {
      App.DeviceIp = ip;
      const url = googleTTS.getAudioUrl(text, {
        lang: "en-US",
        slow: false,
        host: "https://translate.google.com",
      });
      App.GoogleHome(App.DeviceIp, url, function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      });
    },
    broadcast: function (text) {
      const ip = "192.168.0.17";
      App.run(ip, text);
    },
  };

  App.broadcast(message);
  setTimeout(() => {
    App.broadcast(message);
  }, 4000);
}

module.exports = {
  broadcastMessage,
};
broadcastMessage("Incoming message");
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the level to a number between 0 and 1, where 0 is the lowest volume and 1 is the highest volume, i.e: 0.5. Here  client.setVolume({ level: 1 } is at volume is the highest. You could try to save the volume value before change it, send the message with the desired volume, and then restore it again to the previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was I had to define the value before `client.setVolume({ level: 1 }` call
so basically

```
const volume = 0.6;
client.setVolume({ level: volume }
```

Comment: No need to define the volume before `setVolume`. You can do `setVolume({level:0.6}, function`. More importantly, you should see my answer: you should do your actions in the `setVolume` callback in order to be sure that the volume is set before you send the message.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you set the volume in your code to `1`, which is full volume. So, your audio will play at full volume. This is where you *set* the volume:

```
client.setVolume({ level: 1 }, function (err, volume) {
    console.log("VOLUME", volume);
    if (err) {
      // Handle error as appropriate
      console.log("Error on setVolume:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Sending new alert");
    }
});
```

Simply remove this code and your message will play at the volume you set manually on the device.

Also: if you intend to set the volume of the device, you should wait for the callback to return, and only then send the message.

```
client.setVolume({ level: 1 }, function (err, volume) {
    console.log("VOLUME", volume);
    if (err) {
      // Handle error as appropriate
      console.log("Error on setVolume:", err);
    } else {
      // Here you should send the message, since only now you know for sure that the volume was set.
    }
});
```